# AuthUserFile not specified in the configuration error?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I got an error "AuthUserFile not specified in the configuration" in my error log file. how to fix it.
Here is my .htaccess file, its located in amazon file server.

```
## mod auth_mysql
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
AuthMYSQL on
AuthMySQL_Authoritative on
AuthMySQL_DB dbname
Auth_MySQL_Host localhost
Auth_MySQL_User username
Auth_MySQL_Password password
AuthMySQL_Password_Table tbl_name
AuthMySQL_Username_Field user_name
AuthMySQL_Password_Field password
AuthMySQL_Empty_Passwords off
AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types SHA1Sum
# Standard auth stuff
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted zone"

Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 7):

you shall simply put a

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
```

in your .htaccess. That did the trick for me.

for the rest of the pain that brings the configuration of auth_mysql, you have my full comprehension :)

Answer (score 1):

That error isn't refering to your `.htaccess` but rather the main `httpd.conf` Apache configuration file.  Add that line to your `httpd.conf` and then restart your `httpd` service.